# Why will my URDF model not load into Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, ros-melodic, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have developed a simple robot model using a urdf file and several meshes and I am able to load it up in RViz without issue. However, whenever I try to load it into Gazebo it will not appear. I have tried using several methods such as roslaunch and inserting the model into Gazebo itself.

Here is the urdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="Bilkins">


  <link name="chassis">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/chassis.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/chassis.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.2" />
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <link name="rear_axle">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/rear_axle.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="-1.3 0 -0.5" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/rear_axle.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="-1.3 0 -0.5" />
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.14" />
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <link name="front_axle">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/front_axle.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="1.3 0 -0.5" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/front_axle.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="1.3 0 -0.5" />
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1" />
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <link name="front_left_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/front_left_wheel.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="1.3 0.9 -0.5" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/front_left_wheel.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="1.3 0.9 -0.5" />
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.02" />
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <link name="front_right_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/front_right_wheel.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="1.3 -0.9 -0.5" />
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://bilkins/meshes/front_right_wheel.dae" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" />
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="1.3 -0.9 -0.5" />
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.02" />
      <inertia ixx="0.4" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.4" iyz="0.0" izz="0.2"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="rear_axle_to_chassis" type="continuous">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="rear_axle" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="1.3 0 0.5" />
  </joint>

  <joint name="front_axle_to_chassis" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-0.1" upper="0.1" velocity="0.5"/>
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="front_axle" />
    <origin xyz="-1.3 0 0.5" />
  </joint>

  <joint name="front_left_wheel_to_axle" type="continuous">
    <parent link="front_axle"/>
    <child link="front_left_wheel" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0 -0.9 0" />
  </joint>

  <joint name="front_right_wheel_to_axle" type="continuous">
    <parent link="front_axle"/>
    <child link="front_right_wheel" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0 0.9 0" />
  </joint>

</robot>
```

And here is the model.config file that was made for it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <model>
    <name>Bilkins</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <sdf>urdf/bilkins.urdf</sdf>
    <author>
      <name>Andrew Wilkinson</name>
      <email>armwilkinson@gmail.com</email>
    </author>
    <description>
      A small recon drone
    </description>
  </model>
```

This is the repository I have been using for my project:
https://github.com/ARMWilkinson/bilkinsrobot

I am using Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362545/why-will-my-urdf-model-not-load-into-gazebo?/) by [ARMWilkinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/59964/armwilkinson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @ARMWilkinson,

First of all, you do not need a Gazebo model just a [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) or, preferably a [Xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) description. Having said that what you are doing in only loading the `robot_description` in the parameter server, that is the reason why only Rviz is able to see it since Rviz is reading that description from that parameter.

To be able to generate the model in Gazebo you need to call a special python script named "spawner" that it is in change of generating a model in the Gazebo simulation and with the `robot_description` you load. I recommend you to check this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) to learn more about this.

To put things clear, imagine you have your `robot_description` and want to simulate it in Gazebo, Ideally you will have something like:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="model" default="$(find bilkins)/urdf/bilkins.urdf"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true" />
  <arg name="rvizconfig" default="$(find bilkins)/rviz/urdf.rviz" />
  <arg name="output" default="log"/>

  <!-- Coordinates to spawn model -->
  <arg name="x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="z" default="0.01"/>
  <arg name="roll" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="pitch" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="yaw" default="0.0"/>

  <!-- Load model in parameter server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model)" />

  <!-- Generate joint_states and tf_tree -->
  <node if="$(arg gui)" name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui" />
  <node unless="$(arg gui)" name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(arg rvizconfig)" required="true" />

  <!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="$(arg output)"
    args="-urdf -model bilkins_robot -param robot_description -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z) -R $(arg roll) -P $(arg pitch) -Y $(arg yaw)"/>

</launch>
```

So, in order, what you have is: Load URDF in parameter server -> Generate robots `TF_tree` and `joint_states` -> Spawn model in Gazebo.

Hope this helps you.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARMWilkinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/59964/armwilkinson/) on 2020-09-30**:
Thanks, I have tried implementing this but I when I use roslaunch I get an error stating:

RLException: [/home/andrew/catkin_ws/src/bilkinsrobot/launch/gazebo.launch] requires the 'output' arg to be set
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-10-01**:
Ops, I forgot to include that argument. That is on me, sorry. I updated my original answer.

**Comment by [ARMWilkinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/59964/armwilkinson/) on 2020-10-01**:
No worries, I really appreciate the help. The error's no longer appearing now, however, whenever I use roslaunch it opens the model up in RViz.

**Comment by [ARMWilkinson](https://answers.ros.org/users/59964/armwilkinson/) on 2020-10-01**:
Actually scratch that, I've managed to get it loading into Gazebo now. Thank you so much for your help.